# Problemas al instalar TSC

Tags: typescript

Estoy intentando aprender a usar typescript para un curso y tuve que instalarme el Node v17.3.1.
Todo esto desde una Macbook con macOS Catalina 2021-008 10.15.7
Hasta ahí todo bárbaro, lo instalé, sin drama.
Pero para instalar tic me indican que ponga el famoso **npm install -g typescript** desde la terminal, pero cuando le doy Enter me tira todo esto:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'

npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'] {

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',

npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/richardmiranda/.npm/_logs/2022-01-15T20_11_30_277Z-debug-0.log
```

Soy nueva en todo esto y ya de por sí fue un esfuerzo entender cómo acceder a la terminal, así que por favor les pido que me expliquen con peras y palitos cómo resolverlo porque realmente quiero aprender y avanzar en este curso y no puedo hasta no tener TSC instalado.

Gracias desde ya

Comment: Bienvenida! Te recomiendo que [visites la página de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funciona. Aprovecha a editar el código de tu pregunta para añadir cosas que aporten y faciliten la resolución de tus preguntas. Y lo que sea código ponlo con formato código para que se vea mejor 

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te está diciendo el error es que no puede instalar el paquete porque no tiene permisos de escritura en la ubicación que se va a instalar.

Al lanzar el comando con la opción `-g` les estás diciendo que [instale el paquete de manera global](https://lenguajejs.com/npm/introduccion/instalaciones-globales/). Significa que no necesitarás instalarlo en ningún proyecto en particular si no que lo tendrás de manera global en todos tus proyectos (ojo, siempre que lo hagas desde tu ordenador, si luego el archivo de configuración lo usas en otro ordenador necesitarías que tuviese instalado también ese paquete de manera global). Si eso es lo que quieres, genial.

Para que te funcione de esta manera tendrás que lanzarlo con permisos de superusuario, por lo que el comando debería ser `sudo npm install -g typescript`. Te pedirá tu contraseña antes de instalar.

Y si lo que quieres es que se instale de manera particular en tu proyecto el comando será `npm install typescript`.

En mi opinión particular te diría que lo hagas de la segunda manera, y así si el día de mañana lo usas en otro ordenador te ahorras problemas.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.